# facing issue when select a value from combobox in dataGridView cell it have to replace with textBox in same datacell

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox, textbox

below is my comboBox value populate function

```
   If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 And e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row1 = New ArrayList()
        row1.AddRange(New Integer() {1, 2})
        p.Items.AddRange(row1.ToArray())
        DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = p
    End If
```

below function is for after selecting value from comboBox, we have to change that combobox to textbox in same cell

```
    Dim combo1 As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    If combo1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Dim Datas As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        Datas.Value = "S"
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Datas
    End If
```

but comboBox have not replacing to textBox.

getting reply is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Mixing cell types in the same column "may" be doable, however the question would be “why”? How is the combo box column/cell created in the grid? And why do you want to change a grids cell type from a combo box to a text box?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem… you have a problem X… and your Y solution is to change the cell type in the grid. And you present the Y problem here when the actual problem is X.

Comment: If you want the ComboBoxCell to appear as a TextBox when it loses focus and a ComBox when it gets focus, setup the Column with `FillWeight = 1, DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton, DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = true`. Of course, also set its `DataSource` (and `DisplayMember`, eventually).

Answer (score 0):

This is so wrong:

```vb
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Datas
```

You are creating a new cell and then trying to assign that to the `Value` of the existing cell. How does that make sense? You can't have a cell inside a cell and you can't magically change the type of a cell. If you want a cell of a different type then you need to replace the existing cell with a new cell of that type:

```vb
Dim currentCellAddress = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress
Dim columnIndex = currentCellAddress.X
Dim rowIndex = currentCellAddress.Y

DataGridView1(columnIndex, rowIndex) = Datas
```